# Present Perfect vs. Past.... help

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect

Would you please look at my interpretations and correct those respectively?

```
Examples
```

1) She has gone to the store and didn't come back yet.

2) She has gone to the store and hasn't come back yet.

3) She went to the store and didn't come back yet.

4) She went to the store and hasn't come back yet.

```
My thoughts
```

1) The speaker doesn't know when she leaved, but got to know she's not here at some point.

2) The speaker doesn't know when she leaved and when she arrives here.

3) The speaker knows when she leaved, and got to know she's not here at some point.

4) The speaker knows when she leaved, but has no idea when she arrives here.

Comment: In all of your sentences above the speaker doesn't specify when did she leave and when will she come back. "knowing" has nothing to do with those sentences. I also think that the common speaker will just use the simple+simple or the simple+perfect.

Comment: leave, left, left — not *leaved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think 'didn't' sounds unnatural in both #1 and #3. Sentences 2 and 4 mean almost the same thing. #2 uses the present perfect simple tense of the verb 'to go'. #4 uses the past simple tense. I think most people would say #4. By the way, you might find this website helpful: http://www.the-conjugation.com/english/verb/go.php.